# extract value from UIpickerview as variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, uipickerview

so i have this code for a UIpickerview and i want to get the value selected as a variable to use later, i tried using a variable gravity but it says "initialisation of variable gravity was never used...." here's my code:

```
 var g = ["9.807", "3.711"]
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return g.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return g[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    var gravity = Float(g[row])
}
```

Comment: You should read about scope of variables. Now you are defining `gravity` inside `pickerView` function and it does not exist outside of this function.

Comment: Where are you planing to use gravity var? is it the same view controller as the picker?

Comment: yes, the same view controller as the picker

Comment: So just declare  var gravity as a property of  your view controller moving it out of that pickerView  method

Comment: I mean declare `var gravity: Float = 0` in your view controller and inside viewDidLoad method you initialize it with something like this  `gravity =   Float(g[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]) ?? 0`

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much, i appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the var outside of the scope of your method:

```
var gravity: Float?
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   gravity = Float(g[row])
}
```

A local variable scope is limited to the method and as you don't use it within the method you get a warning for that.

This is Swift not Javascript :)

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, i tried this and the error is still present

Comment: There was a typo in my first answer - in the function you don't need to write 'var'. Is that the one you tried?

Comment: yes i tried with 'var', i deleted var and the error disappeared, if you could help me with one more thing please, if i want to use the value of this variable in an equation, like var x = gravity+...
would it work ?

Comment: Yes it's a Float you can do anything with it. The only thing is that we declare it here as an optional, so you'll need to unwrap it 'guard let gravity = gravity else {}'. According to your logic you might make non-optional (removing the ? after it) and setting a default value (e.g. 0).

Comment: i tried this but when i put something like 'var x = gravity + b' (b is an already declared variable with a value' it gives an error

Comment: Have you tried var `x = gravity! + b`? You need an exclamation mark after gravity.

Comment: yes i tried, but i says "cannot use instance member gravity without proper initialiser "

Comment: and gravity is declared as optional, with a question mark after Float?

Answer (score 0):

Your `gravity` var is *local*, so the given warning makes total sense (i.e., its scope is *limited* to the given function).

You should use the following `UIPickerView` method to get the currently selected index:

```
func selectedRow(inComponent component: Int) -> Int
```

For instance:

```
let gIndex = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
let gValue = Float(g[gIndex])!
```

Note that you do *not* even need to implement the `didSelectRow` delegate method to get this information.

As correctly pointed out in the comments, you of course need to declare and bind your `UIPickerView` to an instance var of your view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
```

Comment: @Ace for the second part of this answer you need to connect an IBOutlet to your picker and name it  pickerView if you need to add this to your viewDidLoad method

Comment: i connected the outlet as you said, but adding the value of this var to another variable doesn't seem to work

Comment: my @IBoutlet is already connected exactly as you stated, but the error still exists (sorry i'm a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

To use pickerView, first mention its DataSource and Delegate.

```
UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate
```

Now create this by right clicking on pickerView -> to the ViewContoller.swfit.You will get like:

```
@IBOutlet var pickerView: [UIPickerView]!
```

Create an array which contains the content you want to show in pickerView. Just like this:

```
var array:[String] = ["David","Mikel","Akhil","Akshay","Zlatan"]
```

Now you have to use pickerView functions. These functions can only be used if you mention DataSource and Delegate in class. The functions are:

```
// number of rows or number of components
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// number of rows that we have to set
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

// set title in picker view according to the elements
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return array[row]
}

// when an element is selected, store in a string
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    pickerString = array[row]
    print(pickerString) // pickerString is String type. You can create this, to show the content selected.
}
```